# Change Listview data when i receive a Google Cloud message

Tags: android, listview

i have a app with a listview and an adapter (ArrayAdapter).

Now i have an implementation of GCM with a backend, then when i receive a GCM Message, from the IntentService i need to do a

```
listViewActivityContext.getList().getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I think i need the activity context in the IntentService but i dont know how can i get it and check if its the context for the Activity that contains the ListView.

Anyone has an example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically this is the idea:

Use LocalBroadcastManager, register a listener in your Activity in onCreate() and send a signal from your Service.

Here is a good example:

[how to use LocalBroadcastManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager)

But replace the SenderActivity with your Service.

Answer (score 0):

Register `BroadcastReceiver` in your `Activity`. When you receive push message from `GCM`, send message to registered `BroadcastReceiver` with data received from server, and update your `ListView` in `BroadcastReceiver` `onReceive` method.